# How to combine glyphs in a resizable way for formulas?

Tags: symbols

I want to glue two glyphs together in order to produce a new glyph because I ran out of letters for my formulas. For example, I combine H and K such that the right vertical part of H coincides with the left vertical of K:

```
\newcommand{\HK}{H\hspace*{-0.5em}K}
```

This looks quite good and even scales because of the `em` unit. But in formulas, namely fractions, it doesn't scale properly any more. Which trick solves this?

My minimal example

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
 \begin{document}

 \newcommand{\HK}{H\hspace*{-0.5em}K}

 $\HK$

 $HK$ for comparison.

 {\Large{}$\HK${\Large{}$\HK$}}{\Large \par}

 {\huge{}$\HK$}{\huge \par}

 {\huge{}$\frac{\HK}{2}$}{\huge \par} 

 {$\frac{\HK}{2}$}{\par}

 %{$\frac{\bsHK}{2}$}{\par}
 \end{document}
```

produces

[image: output]

I want the new glyphs in the fractions to look like the preceding ones. By the way, this procedure would also offer a way to kludge bold glyphs if they do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\scriptstyleScaleFactor{0.75}
%\def\scriptscriptstyleScaleFactor{0.5}
\begin{document}

 \newcommand{\HK}{\ThisStyle{H\hspace*{-1.15\LMex}K}}

 $\HK$

 $HK$ for comparison.

 {\Large{}$\HK${\Large{}$\HK$}}{\Large \par}

 {\huge{}$\HK$}{\huge \par}

 {\huge{}$\frac{\HK}{2}$}{\huge \par} 

 {$\frac{\HK}{2}$}{\par}

 %{$\frac{\bsHK}{2}$}{\par}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the advantage of this solution with the ``scalerel`` package?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch None, given that egreg showed it was not needed.  I probably should delete the answer.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch ...although his method does seem to have some issues with `\huge$\HK$` unless my eyes deceive me.

Comment: Please do not delete this answer. +1 for using ``scalerel`` on horizontal spacing. I'm still comparing the answers.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the `em` in the proper size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\HK}{H\text{\hspace*{-0.5em}}K}

\begin{document}

$\HK_{\HK}\frac{\HK}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure your readers will be happy, though.

Comment: I prefer uniqueness to beauty. Spurius Carvilius Ruga is said to have done something similar as he invented the letter "G". ;)

Comment: Why does `\huge$\HK$` look so bad?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Maybe some more kerning is needed in large sizes.